# How to use Unsplash's blur_hash?

Tags: html, reactjs, image

I am fetching images from Unsplash and am using the thumbnail image url. I want to use the blash_hash to show a placeholder while the image loads. How can this be done in a React project?

Here I render the images:

```
<ul>
  {images.map((image) => (
    <li>
      <img src={image.urls.thumb}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

The image from Unsplash has these values:

```
{
  blur_hash :  "LGRfa-?^XTRi-OMxofozyYR4xxxx"
  urls: {
    thumb: '...'
  }
}
```

I am able to display the blurred image, using the `Blurhash` package, as well as the actual image using:

```
<Blurhash
  hash={image.blur_hash}
  width={400}
  height={300}
  resolutionX={32}
  resolutionY={32}
  punch={1}
/>
```

[image]

But how to display the blur image as a placeholder while the image actual loads?

Answer (score 0):

In React, you can track an image's status whether it is loaded or not with `img` component's `onLoad` prop.

I'd create a component that renders `BlurHash` and the actual `img` component depending on that load status.

```
const [isLoaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

return(
   <div>
       <img src={image.urls.thumb} onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)} />
       {!isLoaded && <BlurHash 
        hash={image.blur_hash}
        width={400}
        height={300}
        resolutionX={32}
        resolutionY={32}
        punch={1}  />}
   </div>
)
```

A little css touch may required (to make sure `img` component displayed correctly).

Answer (score 0):

```
const [isImageLoaded, setIsImageLoaded] = useState(false);

function handleImageLoad() {
  setIsImageLoaded(true);
}

return (
  <div>
    {!isImageLoaded && <Blurhash hash={hashValue} width={400} height={300} />}
    <img
      src={imageUrl}
      alt="My Image"
      style={{ display: isImageLoaded ? "block" : "none" }}
      onLoad={handleImageLoad}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: This is essentially the same solution as posted in the other answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate array state with boolean values to keep track of the loaded images for example

const [images, setImages] = useState([]); // normal images state

const [loadedImages, setLoadedImages] = useState([]) // loaded images tracking state

after you are done hitting the API, you can update the above states as follows

```
.then((res) => {
        setImages(res.data);
        setLoadedImages(Array(res.data.length).fill(false));
      })
```

We update the images state with the response and loadedImages state will be an array with false values and it is going to be equal to the length of res.data

Now, your job is to keep track of the images that are done loading and change the false to true at the particular index where image is done loading

```
 // the loaded images will be updated in the loadedImages state
  useEffect(() => {
    if (images.length > 0) {
      const loadImage = (index) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = images[index].urls.regular;
        img.onload = () => {
          setLoadedImages((previousImages) =>
            previousImages.map((loaded, i) => (i === index ? true : loaded))
          );
        };
      };
      images.forEach((_, index) => loadImage(index));
    }
  }, [images]);
```

Now you are good to go. You can show either the image or the blur_hash placeholder if the image is not loaded yet

```
{loadedImages[index] ? (
<img src={image.urls.regular} alt={image.alt_description} />
):(
<Blurhash
          hash={image.blur_hash}
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          resolutionX={32}
          resolutionY={32}
          punch={1}
        />
)
```